# How to track exeception error message during procedure execution

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, exception

I am performing data extractions for my procedured every 1 hour. I want to track exception error message for procedure execution during this extraction such that i can check in my log files and correct it. I write the above code for tracking the error message for one of the procedure i.e `EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN` but didn't work. I have the error in this procedure i.e Unique constratint violated but it wasn't read by `DBMS.OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`

```
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('START EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
DATA_CAPTURING.EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN;
COMMIT;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('STOP EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EXCEPTION START EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN '||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('EXCEPTION' || SQLERRM);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('ERROR CODE' || SQLCODE);
END;
```

Comment: Is this production code? If so, don't use `dbms_output.put_line`; that's something that should only ever be used for ad-hoc things, not production code! Instead, if you want to keep a log of your runs, you should create a log table and then insert into that. Ideally, your `data_capturing.ext_100.5_ws_actman` procedure would also have calls to log to the same table, so that you can track what's happening during the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General common-used way is to use transaction-independed logging via autonomous transactions. Check something like this:

```
create table Log(id integer not null primary key,
                 dt timestamp not null default systimestamp,
                 place varchar2(100 char),
                 message varchar2(2000 char));

create sequence Log_Seq;

create or replace procedure Write(p_Place varchar2, p_Message varchar2) is
  pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  insert into Log (id, place, message)
    values (Log_Seq.nextal, p_Place, p_Message);
  commit;
exception
  when others then
    rollback; 
    raise;
end;

create or replace procedure EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN is
begin
  Write('EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN', 'Start');
  ....
  commit;
  Write('EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN', 'Finish');
exception
  when others then
    Write('EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN', sqlerrm);
    rollback;
    raise;
end;
```

Comment: Hello i am very new to exception handling. I have lots of data extracting from procedure so i cannot insert into new table or cannot use directly into my procedure otherwise it will slow down the performance of my procedure. I have created a new procedure called RUN_EXTRACTION and i am calling other procedures inside this procedure. The code i have mentioned in question is from the RUN_EXTRACTION procedure where i am calling DATA_CAPTURING.EXT_10035_WS_ACTMAN procedure. So thats why i want to use exception handling in that code

Comment: I'm curious why you think writing to file will affect your performance worse than writing to a table. Still, if you are insisting on using DBMS_OUTPUT, ensure that you have first SET SERVEROUPUT ON in your script so that the outputs get caputred, and that your script is spooling output to a log file if being called by SQL*Plus. Because dbms_output only writes to your console at runtime, so you then have to get that into a file so that you can read it.

Comment: your suggestion works perfectly for me. I was avoiding the solution of directly writing exceptions in procedures because i have 50 procedures. I used SET SERVEROUTPUT ON and then use exeception handling and it seems to trap the errors properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off writing an error handler package/procedure, and call it when you have an exception. With the error procedure, write out any related information (procedure name where exception occurred, error code, calling user, and any related data) into either an errors table or to a file.